# clearInterval , stopping a timer on mouseover

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, mouseover, clearinterval

I have for the last few months been back and forth attempting to resolve this problem but i have gotten nowhere, regardless of my attempts... I am finally at my witts end and really need the help for i fear i will loose the will to continue..

If anybody can see my error/ allthough there is none apparent other than the image itself not being directly mousedover as the image is displayed in the html page, i would be greatfull if anybody could help me solve this small but frustrating anomaly...I thank you all in advance..

here is the code.... i have found that i can indeed call the stopped function from the html page. i solution i never tried before in my hurry.

```
var tim=8000



function stopper (){

clearInterval(foot);


console.log (tim)
}



function fader (){


var element = document.getElementById("dynamic-image2");
element.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
<!---the grabbed element + style [ execute type of effect ] = ' dimension of effect (1 ,2)';--->
 element.style.opacity=4;
}

function fader2 (){

var element = document.getElementById("dynamic-image2");
element.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
<!---the grabbed element + style [ execute type of effect ] = ' dimension of effect (1 ,2)';--->
 element.style.opacity=0;
}

   var timer=tim
   var timer2=timer / 2

setInterval( fader2,timer2 );

(function() {
   'use strict';



   var preloads=[],c,
       d=document,di=d.getElementById('dynamic-image2'),
       dh=d.getElementById('dynamic-href2'),
       url=[
           'linkmywebsite.ml','chatmagbingo.com','ilkestonwebdesign.com','ipost.com','happypetsuk.com','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','fireworksnottingham.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','ilkestonfastfood.com','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','de-signz.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','cctautos.com','grundyskips.co.uk','www.m8drivingschools.co.uk','www.apipedream.co.uk','www.crazyskips.com','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.competitiveremovals.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','heartinternet.co.uk','winnerbingo.com','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk','linkmywebsite.ml','katyperry.com','perfectpizza.com','youtube.com','google.com','facebook.com','twitter.com','linkmywebsite.ml','linkmywebsite.ml','gumtree.com'
          ];

        /*adjust to suit */






function preload(){
for(c=0;c<arguments.length;c++) {
   preloads[preloads.length]=new Image();
   preloads[preloads.length-1].src=arguments[c];
  }
   c=0;

 }


preload('yournewsite2.png','1ad.jpg','2ad.jpg',
'3ad.jpg','4ad.jpg','5ad.jpg',
'6ad.jpg','7ad.jpg','8ad.jpg',
'9ad.jpg','10ad.jpg','11ad.jpg',
'12ad.jpg','13ad.jpg','14ad.jpg',
'15ad.jpg','16ad.jpg','17ad.jpg',
'18ad.jpg','19ad.jpg','20ad.jpg',
'21ad.jpg','22ad.jpg','23ad.jpg',
'24ad.jpg','25ad.jpg','26ad.jpg',
'27ad.jpg','28ad.jpg','29ad.jpg',
'30ad.jpg','youtubead.png','googlead.png',
'facebookad.png','twitterad.png','yournewsite2.png',
'yournewsite2.png','gumtreead.png');




setInterval( fader, timer );
```

const foot = setInterval(
    function() {

```
   dh.href='http://'+url[c];
   di.src=preloads[c].src;
   di.alt=preloads[c].src.substring(preloads[c].src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   c++;
if(c==preloads.length) {
   c=0;
  }
 },timer);



}())
```

Comment: Putting it in a JSFiddle may make it easier to help. When do you actually call timerstop()?

Comment: Ok, so what you're doing is calling the anonymous function immediately, which doesn't return the function, which is what you need for the `setInterval`. Do you need it to run immediately? If not, try removing the immeidate call. If you do, create a regular function (aka not anonymous) and pass that as the parameter, and then call it at the same time (separately).

Comment: Im calling the timerstop function from the html page, which is unfortunatly running before the script. And it has too,. no matter  what way around i try i get undecleared element because the script has to run after the image is displayed and the stopper function in the script has to be run after the const... so its looking like a complete re-write ...

Comment: All i want is a mouseover pause....lol - iv tried everything i know how to.. but i get errors at everyturn no matter whether its sound coding or not, i get undeclared because of the layout and structure . so im going to do a re-write i think.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is store the interval in a variable, and then pass that as a parameter to clearInterval.

So as a minimal example

```
const foo = setInterval(func, 1000);
clearInterval(foo);
```

Comment: yes, i have that part. i have just found a solution i think. . i will now impliment your info many thanks...Iv just changed the original code though

Comment: If you can see how i should be doing this let me know, allthough i will be testing your answer also. many thanks.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't do that, which is why I posted my answer.

Comment: yes, i know, but i have tried this before and i couldnt implement onmouse over nonetheless..but i since have figured out i could call a function from the html page as before i thought i couldnot call the function before the script was loaded.

Comment: Was the variable in the proper scope? If you set it in one function, there's no way to access it in the other. You'll want a higher scope, such as global (which isn't recommended, but it works).

Comment: The trouble im having at the minuate is this exactly, i cannot call the stopper function before the const , and visa versa...

Comment: Please put code in an edit to the post. It doesn't work well in comments :)

Comment: here is a jsfiddle for any1 who can master it ...thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rodfeqya/

Comment: I'll go through it, but it's _very_ difficult to follow, as the code lacks proper indenting.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to update it a fair amount for me to be able to do anything. I tried formatting everything [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rodfeqya/1/). You didn't even provide the full HTML that the JS expects.

Comment: sorry, i was trying to minimal...i shall update it in full..

Comment: I'll take a look at it in the morning, as I'm on mobile now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qfdLxt9j/4/   ---Here is a updated and cleaner fiddle But function stopper, is not being called in the fiddle... or its not doing anything... In my page. i cannot call it because its being called before the script is run and i cannot place the function anywhere else where it could be called from, so its a bit tricky... But if anybody manages a Pause on mouseover, i would be interested to know how it was done, Iv tried a few things other than a re-write..

Comment: Ok thanks Jhpratt. Il look forward to it. cant say im likely to find a work around in the meantime to be honest , so would greatly appreciate any help you may have to offer. thank you.

Comment: As I had said before, there's not even the HTML that it expects. You have to have `#dynamic-href2`, which is on line 30 of your JS. I'm going to step away from this at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway...Just for record, its not my scripting or coding, its a copy from elsewhere (a fairly common freebee), But i adapted it with my own image list is all.. But im going to re-write it to suit a mouseover pause When & if i can figure out a way to call it without undefined errors.